# Actioncable authentication with multiple Devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am currently implementing a chat between 2 of my Devise models. `Client` and `Professionnel`. It is working just fine at the moment but I have only one channel: every Client or Professionnel receive all messages from all clients and all professionals. The displaying is fine but someone who watches their AJAX flow can see every private message that is not meant for them..

As per this thread http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/rails-5-action-cable-with-multiple-chatroom-subscriptions/ this is called **single responsibility principle**

So I am trying to create "sub streams" in order to broadcast to the right users.

My first step is authing with Devise. I am using the classic :

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
        self.current_user = find_verified_user
        logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email       
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
        if verified_user = env['warden'].user
          verified_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
    end

  end
end
```

And this is where the problem arises: when a Client is logged in, Actioncable is not creating a connection:

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-16 22:30:28 +0200
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-16 22:30:28 +0200
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive, Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected
```

But when a Professionel logs in everything is ok :

```
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive, Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  Professionnel Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "professionnels".* FROM "professionnels" WHERE "professionnels"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "professionnels"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActionCable] [dummy@gmail.com] Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vcm9vZnNlZWRzL1Byb2Zlc3Npb25uZWwvMQ)
```

This is very strange as in both case the session cookie shows a warden related id, either when Client or Professionel is logged :

```
["session_id", "0c3649a0e924de3fbf14dbb1cf2ce058"] ["flash", {"discard"=>[], "flashes"=>{"notice"=>"Connecté."}}] ["professionnel_return_to", "/"] ["warden.user.client.key", [[1], "$2a$12$auNvgciv6qPDf7n5a93vXu"]]

["session_id", "43a9b6db09311473419d7f22f2ce6419"] ["flash", {"discard"=>[], "flashes"=>{"notice"=>"Connecté."}}] ["warden.user.professionnel.key", [[1], "$2a$12$qZ4whbN3e2w7fn8NJWa/B."]] ["professionnel_return_to", "/"] ["_csrf_token", "sZA8gze5lxU6R71XUci0uQDXVk+d75VslI90ImcjwhA="]
```

I dont get where the error comes from ..

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

Just found this piece of code in Devise initializer :

```
  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
  # config.default_scope = :user
```

Professionnel is indeed my first Devise role declared in my routes. Does it has anything to do with my problem ? And How can I solve this ?

```
    devise_for :professionnels, controllers: {registrations: "professionnels/registrations", passwords: "professionnels/passwords", confirmations: "professionnels/confirmations"}
    devise_for :clients, controllers: {registrations: "clients/registrations", passwords: "clients/passwords", confirmations: "clients/confirmations"}
    devise_for :admins, controllers: {registrations: "admins/registrations", sessions: "admins/sessions"}
```

Comment: I notice that the professionel cookie has a CSRF token and the client one doesn't... is that relevant?

Comment: Well, actually both show a CSRF token but it only appaears on first page change or page refresh after login. Professionnel log in on a dedicated page but client log in on the root page. When I log in as a Professionnel I have to go back to root in order to view the cookie I have implemented on the root view, then CSRF adds up. But when I log in as client and reload root, CSRF gets added too (with no change to Actioncable authing)

Comment: Someone seems to have an unusual behavior like me : https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/69m9fm/actioncable_with_devise_multiple_models/ But in my case the Warden env is not blank. It is just it is not recognised or retrieved.

Comment: Hi @TarynEast I have edited my question with something that may be meaningful. Do you see a solution to this scope thing ? When I switch the first and second positions of the Devise models in routes, then Client get authed !!! It seems to tbe the problem ...

Comment: I notice there are some minor differences between your implementation and what's in the docs here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models eg the example routes have `path` in them, which yours don't... I'd look at what's in the dos and add any differnces until your works :D

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. All the Devise part are working well but I will add a path and see if anything changes. All models are also resources and have extra custom paths. Regarding warden it's fixed. But Actioncable is tough. For example I can see people using params in the channel file on some threads on the internet. But to me the channel file is not erb file nor a controller that could be recipient of a form.. lots of things don't behave such as a begginer like me would think it does

Comment: yeah I haven't really played with ActionCable yet myself (its' on my looong TODO list)... so sadly my advice is limited to my understanding of Devise... and that's limited to just eyeballing and comparing the docs to what you have... ;)

Answer (score 7):

Ok  the answer is simple: if you have multiple Devise accounts to auth into Actioncable, you have to scope warden for each of them, in my case connection.rb looks like :

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
        self.current_user = find_verified_user
        logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email       
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
        if verified_user = env["warden"].user(:professionnel)
          verified_user
        elsif verified_user = env["warden"].user(:client)
          verified_user    
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
    end


  end
end
```

In this case I give them the same identifier as the chatroom is a child of both of them so I ( guess I) can treat them the same. I think it is possible to give them different identifiers if needed.