# ruby on rails Action cable with two Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am implementing a chat between two of my devise model pro and user. I succeed in making the connection but there is an error while calling message from the send devise model which is pro while another one is working.

I implemented this with the help from this link 
https://www.nopio.com/blog/rails-real-time-chat-application-part-1/
https://www.nopio.com/blog/rails-chat-application-actioncable/

and authentication both models with the help of this 
[Actioncable authentication with multiple Devise models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866041/actioncable-authentication-with-multiple-devise-models)

everything is fine but I got an error of if logged in from pro model.

This is the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
1: <li>
2:   <div class="row">
3:     <div class="<%= user.id == message.user_id ? 'message-sent' : 
'message-received' %>">
4:       <%= message.body %>
5:     </div>
6:   </div>
```

Comment: unless you create a local variable `user` I think you need the devise helper which is `current_user` right?  Does it fix it to change that to `current_user.id` ?

Comment: not worked for me. i have tried it. can you give me idea about alternate ways to implement this or give me some code link like GitHub so i can understand more....actually i am beginner to action-cable

Comment: Well the issue is that the `user` variable is empty so whatever value is being set to that is not happening when you view the page in the way you are.  Can you show the code where the `user` variable is getting it's value?

Comment: @RockwellRice that was not an issue my issue is that it is not getting that id for different devise model

Comment: Sure, the error is `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass):`  The method here `id` is attached to the `user` variable.  That variable is not getting anything in it, so once that is worked out this will be fixed, I think we are saying the same thing, so, where does the user variable get it's value?